Carrying Out Geometry Optimisations in CASTEP, Energies Increasing And Calculations Run Indefinitely
I’m using PW-DFT to model a molecular crystal and I’m now attempting to optimise strained structures for these molecular crystals.
I am reducing one of the lattice parameters, freezing it, and then allowing the remaining lattice parameters and cell angles to fluctuate. I have successfully carried out these calculations for compressions of 0.1, 0.2, and 0.3 Angstroms. However, when try to reduce the lattice parameter by a total of 0.4 Angstroms the GeomOpt calculation continues indefinitely, and the energy of the structure actually increases.
I have used PBE level of theory and tested these calculations with a variety of dispersion corrections; I am using the TPSD geometry method - the same issue arises regardless. I’ve played around with the convergence criteria, loosening them to no avail.
I’m using the following convergence criteria in the .param file:
ELEC_ENERGY_TOL: 1.00E-05
GEOM_DISP_TOL: 1.00E-03
GEOM_ENERGY_TOL: 2.00E-03
GEOM_STRESS_TOL: 0.10
GEOM_MAX_ITER: 1000
GEOM_MODULUS_EST: 60
GEOM_FORCE_TOL: 0.01

I really would appreciate some help. Thank you.
EDIT 26/12/2024:
Here is the content of the .cell input file I'm using for the calculation, where I've applied 0.4 Angstroms of compression
# CELL file written 23:13:41 (GMT+0.0) 21st December 2024 from run tatnbz
%BLOCK lattice_ABC
   ANG
       9.122932                8.715419               6.815499
       108.386704              93.126093              117.757291       
%ENDBLOCK lattice_ABC
%BLOCK cell_constraints
      1   0   3
      4   5   6
%ENDBLOCK cell_constraints
%BLOCK positions_frac
   H                0.485454443789207       0.849718796172040       0.244863092654110
   H                0.514545548043869       0.150281192420544       0.755136880408826
   H                0.262034266260993       0.739935964098158       0.234601958350245
   H                0.737965726688323       0.260064029236490       0.765398020848837
   H                0.972882886282113       0.070883403259703       0.265848248691034
   H                0.027117116589963       0.929116602472141       0.734151762139628
   H                0.081308434450030       0.299136851863370       0.259051754715244
   H                0.918691570075899       0.700863155110431       0.740948259884382
   H                0.669304547312967       0.579988231346874       0.242681286882591
   H                0.330695459065515       0.420011775982502       0.757318734812010
   H                0.783168270506409       0.460922092579941       0.254866665418284
   H                0.216831731744314       0.539077908247920       0.745133342284355
   C                0.531984856669464       0.163209481926855       0.256975785065375
   C                0.468015141080963       0.836790513544141       0.743024204612759
   C                0.375480309181924       0.003508987608684       0.249795963597312
   C                0.624519687239703       0.996491007365044       0.750204022267438
   C                0.220380184312007       0.010254161452502       0.249313969759071
   C                0.779619814855385       0.989745838552585       0.750686028496205
   C                0.218909666761949       0.173145739709222       0.250730608521814
   C                0.781090335267250       0.826854263892913       0.749269399119634
   C                0.374404424504316       0.326707160583388       0.243863607787964
   C                0.625595578480554       0.673292843421623       0.756136402082038
   C                0.532573652769495       0.325145580722183       0.249772392634182
   C                0.467426348987278       0.674854420797327       0.750227612572797
   N                0.686480076477997       0.159238764133885       0.265306796942044
   N                0.313519919008862       0.840761226790221       0.734693183482264
   N                0.374389527490239       0.851606520867657       0.242078442722803
   N                0.625610465340780       0.148393469803837       0.757921530885486
   N                0.067080316534267       0.854311398863063       0.248519809131246
   N                0.932919682615999       0.145688602394410       0.751480191765612
   N                0.078597740039680       0.182465033808586       0.259642630235624
   N                0.921402263731304       0.817534972557991       0.740357383252958
   N                0.372568593435074       0.484035871804181       0.236652158496003
   N                0.627431411584002       0.515964134967233       0.763347858386922
   N                0.674792134517557       0.468781926285119       0.249423784230943
   N                0.325207869397494       0.531218077851652       0.750576230127970
   O                0.823734149812377       0.296867073195305       0.272135626418824
   O                0.176265847221664       0.703132918856751       0.727864359639883
   O                0.689766825360085       0.017556585477672       0.264769122986438
   O                0.310233166577145       0.982443400388841       0.735230843344634
   O                0.063963815362255       0.709466739281549       0.244387396385740
   O                0.936036180626301       0.290533257760479       0.755612592403999
   O                0.931024103660095       0.858928960975988       0.251455108573897
   O                0.068975898694537       0.141071045769839       0.748544907065136
   O                0.237381552714870       0.490460303108723       0.229759628078948
   O                0.762618452454051       0.509539704004041       0.770240388441111
   O                0.507415680070771       0.623390977737044       0.238650571870698
   O                0.492584326352708       0.376609030949358       0.761349451524683
%ENDBLOCK positions_frac
FIX_COM : true
%BLOCK species_pot
NCP
%ENDBLOCK species_pot
kpoint_mp_grid :    3   3   4


It's quite hard to comment definitively, but either you are nearer a phase transition than you thought, or are getting atoms which are very close to each other. Without seeing your input files it is hard to say!                                  Are you starting each run from the endpoint of the previous run? It may also be worth increasing your elec energy tol slightly.

Hi Robert. Merry Christmas to you and thanks for your reply. And I can confirm Im using the optimised structures from the previous runs: so for a compression of 0.2 A I will use the output file .cell file from the converged run where I compressed by 0.1 A. I’ll try to increase the elec energy tol. Is there a way I can send you the input files Im using so you can take a look?

@RobertLawrence Pinging so you will see frankcastle's comment. (The poster of a question will see all comments, but you need to reference other users for them to get notifications).

@Tyberius Thank you, Tyberius. I'll make sure to do that in future.

Hi Robert, just an update but I took your advice to increase the elec energy tol slightly and have set it to 10^-4. I have also played around a bit more with the parameters, and these are the new updated parameters I'm using. ELEC_ENERGY_TOL: 1.00E-04
GEOM_DISP_TOL: 1.00E-04
GEOM_ENERGY_TOL: 5.00E-07
GEOM_STRESS_TOL: 0.01
GEOM_MAX_ITER: 1000
GEOM_MODULUS_EST: 60
GEOM_FORCE_TOL: 0.005

@RobertLawrence Hi Robert, I've added the input file I'm using in the main body of the post.

+1 but please remove the blank lines between each line in your code block.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime My apologies, Nike. I'll fix that now.

Thanks for your attempt, but your edit did not fix it!

Hey Frankcaastle, one obvious booboo is that the elec energy tol is higher than the geom energy tol; that will make convergence practically impossible. (I usually try and make elec energy tol at least one order of magnitude better than geom energy tol as that helps prevent trying to optimise away noise.) A geom force tol of 5e-3 also implies a 1e-6 elec energy tol as forces converge roughly as the square root of the total energy.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Hi Nike, I do apologise. I realize I had forgotten to remove the spacings in the first section of my post. I'll correct that now. Hope your day is going well.

@RobertLawrence Hi Robert, I've set off another calculation with the recommended advice. I'll keep you updated as to how it progresses.

After taking look at the energies after about 10 hours, it appears they are increasing. Regarding the input file I’m using, do you have any thoughts?
